# Self adjoint operator and vertex conditions in quantum graphs

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

Let $\Gamma$ be a metric graph with finitely many edges. Consider the operator H acting as $\frac{-d^2}{dx_e^2}$ on each edge $e$, with the domain consisting of functions that belong to $H^2(e)$ on each edge $e$ and satisfy the boundary condition $A_vF + B_vF' = 0$ at each vertex. Here $\{A_v, B_v :v \in V\}$ is a collection of matrices of sizes $d_v \times d_v$ (Here $d_v$ is the number of edges that are connected to v) such that each matrix $(A_v \; B_v)$ has the maximal rank. In order for H to be self-adjoint, the following condition at each vertex is necessary and sufficient:

$\textrm{the matrix }A_vB_v^*\textrm{ is self-adjoint.}$

This is a theorem from: *P. Kuchment. Quantum Graphs I. Some Basic Structures. Texas A\& M University*.

He says that proof can be found in *V. Kostrykin and R. Schrader. Kirchhoff's rule in quantum wires* but does someone know more direct proof? In the second paper they use maximal isotropic subspaces but I would like not to use that.

Thank you very much.

Comment: These things usually boil down to exercises in (symplectic) linear algebra. The operator will be self-adjoint precisely if it is symmetric and a restriction of the maximal operator of the right dimension, as indicated by the deficiency indices.

Answer (score 1):

A more direct proof can be found in the book "Introduction to Quantum Graphs", http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=SURV-186,
Theorem 1.4.4